# Logfile header in winston?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I am using winston for file logging. Now I want to have some header lines at the top of each file. Within the documentation is nothing written. DO I have to make my own file transport or is there any possibility to do so?
Can I configure a static header of some lines to be added if a new file is created?

Answer (score -1):

Winston loggers are EventEmitters, as mentioned here:

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#events-and-callbacks-in-winston

The code does show that an `open` event is emitted which might be the right place to try to log your static header.

Maybe give something like this a try.

```
logger.on('open', function (fullname) {
    logger.info('This is my custom log file header.');
});
```

Comment: Will that also insert the header again if I restart the service meaning winston has to reopen an already existing file? That's not completely what i want. But if nothing else is possible I have to look if this makes a problem in Analyzation if the header comes multiple times.

Comment: That is a good point, I am not sure if that will happen but it does seem likely. There was a feature request on the Winston project for a specific event to be fired on a log rotation for someone who also wants to log something in that case. https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/517

Comment: The open event comes too late. It is emitted after the first line is written so also if i diectrly write using `logger._stream.write()` it comes to late. I have to make an issue there.